# Proving consistency of a two-way random effects model estimator

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

In the standard two-way random effects model, it is assumed that

$$ X_{ij} = A_i + U_{ij}, (j = 1,\ldots ,m\,;~i = 1, \ldots ,s)$$

with the A’s and U’s all independently, normally distributed with

$$\begin{aligned}
E(A_i) &= \xi ~, &\mathrm{Var}(A_i) &= \sigma_A^2 \\
E(U_{ij}) &= 0~, & \mathrm{Var}(U_{ij}) &= \sigma^2\end{aligned}$$

**Prove that**

$$\bar{X} = \frac{\sum \sum X_{ij}}{sm}$$

is:

1) Not consistent for $\xi$ if $m → \infty$ and $s$ remains fixed,

2) Consistent for $\xi$ if $s → \infty$ and m remains fixed.

**Where I'm stucked:**

i) From the sufficient condition for $Y_n \xrightarrow{p} c$ (Convergence in probability), i.e. $E(Y_n - c)^2 \to 0$ :

$$\bar{X} \xrightarrow{p}  \xi \quad \text{if} \quad E(\bar{X} - \xi)^2 \to 0, n \to \infty$$
Therefore
$$\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X}) = \mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{\sum \sum X_{ij}}{sm} \right) = \frac{1}{s^2m^2} \mathrm{Var}(\sum \sum X_{ij}) =  \frac{1}{s^2m^2} \mathrm{Var} \left( \sum \sum A_i + U_{ij} \right)$$

Let $h_{ij} = \mathrm{Var}(\sum \sum A_i + U_{ij})$, then I have to prove that

$$h_{ij} = o(s^2 m^2)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Consistency of a estimator can be assessed throughout it's convergence in probability, i.e. if $\bar{X} \xrightarrow{p} \xi$, then $\bar{X}$ is a **consistent estimator** of $\xi$.

Using *convergence in quadratic mean* as a sufficient condition to ensure consistency, we will have:

\begin{equation*}
E[\bar{X} - \xi]^2 \to 0,
\quad\text{as}\quad n \to \infty
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E[\bar{X} - \xi]^2 & = Var[\bar{X}] \\
& = Var\left[ \frac{1}{s m} \sum \sum X_{ij} \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} Var\left[ \sum \sum X_{ij} \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} Var\left[ \sum \sum (A_i + U_{ij}) \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} \left\lbrace Var\left[\sum \sum A_i\right]  + Var\left[ \sum \sum U_{ij} \right]  \right\rbrace \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} \left\lbrace Var\left[m \sum A_i \right] + Var\left[ \sum \sum U_{ij} \right] \right\rbrace \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} \left\lbrace m^2 Var\left[\sum A_i \right] + Var\left[\sum \sum U_{ij} \right] \right\rbrace \\
& = \frac{1}{s^2 m^2} \left\lbrace m^2 s Var\left[A_i \right] + s m Var\left[ U_{ij} \right] \right\rbrace \\
& = \frac{m^2 s}{s^{2} m^2} Var[A_i] + \frac{s m }{s^{2} m^{2}} Var[U_{ij}] \\
& = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{s} + \frac{\sigma^2}{s m}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now checking for the cases 1. and 2.

1. Not consistent for $\xi$ if $m \to \infty$ and $s$ remains fixed.

$lim_{m \to \infty}\left\lbrace  \frac{\sigma_A^2}{s} + \frac{\sigma^2}{s m} \right\rbrace = \frac{\sigma_A^2}{s}$

2. Consistent for $\xi$ if $s \to \infty$ and $m$ remains fixed.

$\lim_{s \to \infty}\left\lbrace  \frac{\sigma_A^2}{s} + \frac{\sigma^2}{s m} \right\rbrace = 0$

$\therefore \bar{X}$ is **consistent** as $s \to \infty$ and $m$ remains fixed.